# Photos Framework : contentMode within RequestImageForAsset method

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6, photosframework

In Photos Framework, I'm trying to review a tutorial that uses The RequestImageFor Asset method from the PHImageManager.

Here is the piece of code:

```
    let asset:PHAsset = self.photoAsset[indexPath.item] as! PHAsset
    PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .AspectFill, options: nil, resultHandler: {(result:UIImage!, info:NSDictionary!)in
       cell.setThumbnailImage(result)
    })
```

I've got a compiler issue on the second line : "Could not find member 'AspectFill'

I cant't understand why as it is in the definition of PHImageContentMode :

```
@availability(iOS, introduced=8.0)

enum PHImageContentMode : Int { 
PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryMode and PHImageRequestOptionsResizeMode)
case AspectFit 
case AspectFill
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

try omitting the explicit type declaration for `info` on your `resultHandler`.

It fixed it for me.